# how to use interaction use in sequence diagram in Staruml

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, staruml

I have created two sequence diagrams and I wanted to reference one of them in the other, I know to do that we have to use interaction use, but I can't write on it or reference the other sequence diagram, I tried to see the documentation but it's not helping, can anyone tell me please how to do it?